# Approximating a bounded measurable function from below by a sequence of smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded measurable function.

> Is it possible to find a sequence of functions $\{f_n \}_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ in $C^{\infty}_c( \mathbb{R})$  such that  $f_n(x) \uparrow f(x)$, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

This seems to be true without the assumption that the convergence is from below, by standard results from the literature. However, I am really not sure about this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It can be shown that a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous on a dense set. [This is a consequence of Baire Category Theorem]. However, a bounded measurable function can be discontinuous at every point.

Comment: Heyy, really like your answer, if you could help with an exercise, would really appreciate it :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096022/normed-vector-space-schauder-basis-exercise