# Do weak convergence and convergence of norms imply convergence in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I know this does hold in $L^2$, since it's a Hilbert space.

I suspect that this is not true, but I cannot think of a counterexample.

Specifically, I want to know if $f_n \xrightarrow{w} f$ and $\Vert f_n \Vert \rightarrow \Vert f \Vert$ implies $\Vert f_n -f \Vert \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700003932  This seems to answer your question, without needing convergence of norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It $\textit{is}$ true in $L^2:\ \|f-f_n\|^2=\|f\|^2-2\langle f,f_n\rangle+\|f_n\|^2\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ In fact, the result is true for $f\in L^p:\ 1<p<\infty$ because these spaces are reflexive.

For a nice counterexample in $L^1([0,2])$, see [the comment here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/weak-convergence-in-lp-plus-convergence-of-norm-implies-strong-convergence).

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant it *is* true in $L^2$ since I had already shown that it holds for Hilbert spaces

Comment: OK. The proof for general $1<p<\infty$ is a great exercise!

Comment: @Matematleta: For the $L^p$ case: It is really sufficient to know that these spaces are reflexive? I always thought that you need the uniform convexity of these spaces?

Comment: Heyy, really like your answer, if you could help with an exercise, would really appreciate it :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096022/normed-vector-space-schauder-basis-exercise

Comment: @Homaniac Sure. I will look at it.

Comment: @gerw For some reason, I thought the two notions were equivalent in $L^p;\ 1<p<\infty.$ Maybe because  I know a proof that does not even use uniform convexity. But uniform convexity is stronger, Thanks!